# Python - How to keep the tensorflow model in memory?

Tags: python, nginx, tensorflow

I want to call the tensorflow and load a model to resolve something randomly, how to keep the model in memory to prevent loading the model so many times and waste so much time?

backend: python-tensorflow
frontend: Nginx

Comment: Reduce the size of your model...

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/saved_model#save_and_restore_models